# Reversing the Operand of Smart Matching operator doesn't give same result

Tags: perl

I am facing a strange problem here in the working of `Smart Matching Operator`..

I have read that the order of operand while using the `Smart Matching Operator(~~)` doesn't matter, and it gives the same result.. But in an example which I have shown below, this doesn't work..

I want to check whether an element is amongst one of the elements of a given array or not..

Below are the two ways I tried : -

**First way: -** ($result ~~ @nums)

```
#!/perl/bin
use v5.14;

my @nums = qw( 1 2 3 27 42 );
my $result = 27;

say "The result [$result] is one of the input values (@nums)" if $result ~~ @nums;
```

**Second way: -** (@nums ~~ $result)

```
#!/perl/bin
use v5.14;

my @nums = qw( 1 2 3 27 42 );
my $result = 27;

say "The result [$result] is one of the input values (@nums)" \
                                 if @nums ~~ $result;
```

However, the first way is working fine, and it is printing the statement, but in the second way, it is not printing..

i.e. : - **`@nums ~~ $result`** is not giving the same result as **`$result ~~ @nums`**

I can't understand why this is happening..

Can anyone help me. I am unable to find this problem on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to to the [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator), it says (among many other stuff):

> It is often best read aloud as "in", "inside of", or "is contained
>   in", because the left operand is often looked for inside the right
>   operand.

you may want to look at the table there, especially on the following sections:

```
Left      Right      Description and pseudocode                               
===============================================================
Any       ARRAY      smartmatch each ARRAY element[3]                   
                like: grep { Any ~~ $_ } ARRAY
Any       Num        numeric equality                                  
                 like: Any == Num
```

and remember that if `Any` is array and `Num` is a scalar, the following are equal:

```
Any == Num <=> scalar(Any) == Num
```

Comment: @soulSurfer2010.. Thanks.. But, that would mean, order of operands actually matter sometimes.. Then I would need to remember that table :)

Comment: @soulSurfer2010.. One thing I need to ask.. Since `in` operator is also there to check for containment of element in Array.. So, which one should we use - `in` or `~~`??

Comment: @RohitJain Perl doesn't have an `in` operator.

Comment: Agree with @amon, no in op (you probably getting confused with javascript / bash / java,...)

Comment: If `Any` is an array, then its reference is what gets matched against the right operand: `@a=1..2;@a~~2` is not a match, nor is `@a=1..2;@a~~"1 2"` (stringification of array), but `@a=1..2;$b="".\@a;@a~~$b` is a match.